# How to define bytes in Ocaml?

Tags: byte, ocaml, bit

This is how I'm currently defining bytes and bits for a program in `ocaml`:

```
type bit = Zero of int | One of int

type byte_t = bit * bit * bit * bit * bit * bit * bit * bit

type block = byte_t * byte_t * byte_t * byte_t * byte_t * byte_t
```

These are super lengthy definitions, and will cause a lot of problems while implementation.

Is there a better way to implement these?

Answer (score 2):

In the real world OCaml programming, we normally use `char` for the data type for bytes. It has 8bits.

Your definition of `bit` is strange. It should be simply:

```
type bit = Zero | One
```

or you can use `bool` instead.

If you are working on homework or something to learn algebraic way of data construction, the story may be different.

Comment: You can use strings of length 6 for your blocks (with same caveat about homework).